# CSS full-page-width horizontal menu and horizontal submenu

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

I am trying to create a solution for a website I am working on in which menus and sub-menus are horizontally centred, but the divs extend to full page width.

First off, here is a sample HTML:

```
<div id="menu-container" class="full-width">
    <nav id="nav1" class="normal-width">
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li id="item1">
                <a href="#">item 1</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="item11">
                        <a href="#">item 1.1</a>
                    </li>

                    <li id="item12">
                        <a href="#">item 1.2</a>
                    </li>

                    <li id="item13">
                        <a href="#">item 1.3</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="item2">
                <a href="#">item 2</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="item21">
                        <a href="#">item 2.1</a>
                    </li>

                    <li id="item22">
                        <a href="#">item 2.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="item3">
                <a href="#">item 3</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The CSS for this menu is:

```
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}

.normal-width {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.main-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}

.main-menu > li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:2em;
}

.sub-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    display:none;
    background-color: orange;
}

.sub-menu li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:2em;
}

.main-menu > li.selected {
    background-color:orange;
}

.main-menu > li.selected .sub-menu {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

And the jQuery associated is:

```
// Add a clear div to allow adding background color to main-menu
$(".main-menu").append("<div class='clear'></div>");

// Make the first class selected
$(".main-menu > li:first").addClass("selected");

// Switch the selected class
$(".main-menu > li").click(function() {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});

// Disable menu links
$(".main-menu > li > a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

All that is nice and dandy, and a proper horizontal menu is created. What I am struggling with and I am unable to create is what you can see in this picture: 
[image]

Note the following about the picture:

1. The black thick border around the picture is the webpage full size and width (i.e, the browser window borders)
2. The thin vertical purple lines in the middle are not visible, they are in the picture to show you where the content would be, i.e, no content will go over to the far left or far right sides of the purple lines
3. The top level menu items have the red background
4. The sub menues will appear in the area with the orange background

Now, to the problem:

**Notice how the red and yellow backgrounds extend to the webpage edges, yet the items of those pages appear within the content area inside the purple lines**. This is what I am trying to achieve but unable to. I am unable to extend the backgrounds to the edges of the web browser (i.e., full-page width). **My solutoin centres the red and orange backgrounds in the middle.**

Comment: How do you want the menu to extend to the edges of the page when you give the menu a width of 1024px? Also, please attach your existing css or a fiddle

Comment: Great point, I missed adding the container, let me fix that.

Comment: I just fixed that and added a wrapper div. However, this might affect the submenu, and therefore there might be a need for another div after the main div just for illusion of a container, but again, this is just a thought.

Comment: i think you will have to go to JQuery and display the sub menu as in a separate div on main menu click event, and simple styling will make your menu like in that of the link.

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery, simple javascript will work prefectly

Comment: Either way, jQuery or JavaScript. But I was hoping without that. However, that said, what is the solution? :)

Comment: The question was edited, comletely overhauled, to reflect an understanding of the problem. I think the question was not originally worded properly.

Comment: A former company of mine did this. The full-width box held a single background image, of which you only saw the top part on page load. Once a user clicked a menu item to show the submenu item, there was then always a submenu present; the presence of the submenu naturally increased the height of the fullwidth box, showing more of the background image (which in your case would be two colours). If you need flexibility, you can use CSS gradients with a harsh division based on % heights. so 50% red then 50% yellow after a menu item is activated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am adding the final answer here, for the sake of ensuring that every one sees the answer I chose (i.e, for the greater good).

This answer is inspired by GraphicO, with modifications:

The HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="main-menu" >
        <li id="item1">
            <a href="#">item 1</a>

            <div>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="item11">
                        <a href="#">item 1.1</a>
                    </li>

                    <li id="item12">
                        <a href="#">item 1.2</a>
                    </li>

                    <li id="item13">
                        <a href="#">item 1.3</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li id="item2">
            <a href="#">item 2</a>

            <div>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="item21">
                        <a href="#">item 2.1</a>
                    </li>

                    <li id="item22">
                        <a href="#">item 2.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li id="item3">
            <a href="#">item 3</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Then, the CSS:

```
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: red;
}

.main-menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;

    list-style: none;
}

.main-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2em;
}

.main-menu > li.selected {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.main-menu > li > div { /* nested div (containing the sub nav) will be hidden by default */
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;

    background-color: yellow;
    display:none;
}

.main-menu > li.selected > div {
    display: inline;
}

.sub-menu {
    list-style: none;

    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
}

.sub-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2em;
}
```

And finally the jQuery:

```
// Make the first class selected
$(".main-menu > li:first").addClass("selected");

// Switch the selected class
$(".main-menu > li").click(function() {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});

// Disable menu links
$(".main-menu > li > a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution I came up with.

Edited:  I copied my answer to the post, rather than linking to jsfiddle... sorry mods :/

CSS:

```
html, body, div, ul, li, a {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
nav {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.25em 1em;
}
nav > ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
}
nav ul li div { /* nested div (containing the sub nav) will be hidden by default */
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
nav ul li div ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a {  /* swap ":hover" with ".active" to allow this to work as a class */
    background-color: #ccc;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > div { /* swap ":hover" with ".active" to allow this to work as a class */
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">item 1</a>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">item 1.1</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">item 1.2</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">item 1.3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">item 2</a>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">item 2.1</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">item 2.2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">item 3</a>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">item 3.1</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">item 3.2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">item 4</a>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">item 4.1</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">item 4.2</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">item 4.3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Take a look, test it on your own and see if it will solve your problem.

Notes:

- I used `:hover` in the css, just so you can actually see the changes taking place.
- To implement this the way you want to do it, you will either need to hard-code the class "active" to your top level list items... OR... you could use some javascript to do it more dynamically.
- you will see the last two lines of css  where i left comments... just replace the `:hover` with `.active`
- the only thing that I needed to add to the html were some container
  divs to wrap each sub menu.  this was the only way i could find to
  center your sub nav on the page.. while allowing a band of color to stretch across the page.

my css might be a bit messy, but thats just because I kinda threw it together.  It is up to you to style it they way you want it to look.

Hope you like it!  Let me know if you need any clarification.

Edit:  oh forgot to mention.. I got rid of all the id's and classes you had in there, they weren't needed for the functionality... but if you want to associate specific colors with specific sub menus, then you will want to put a few id's back in.

Comment: -1, please post your code in the actual answer. I will undownvote when you do.

Comment: Is it possible to do this solution without adding the `<div>` around the inner `<ul>`  tag?

Comment: technically, yes there is... but it will not be easy... you will need to create very specific widths and margins for each child `<li>` in your sub menus... and if all your sub menus have different number of links, you will have to create individual styles specific for each one... which will cause more headaches, believe me.  This is the best method i can find that will center your menu and also not depend on individual styling.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, this should get you on your way:

http://jsfiddle.net/X7T94/

It does require putting `class="active"` on the main-menu li that you want as the active item. The rest of your HTML is the same. CSS:

```
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}

.normal-width {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
.main-menu > li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-right:30px;
}
.sub-menu {
    display:none;
}
.sub-menu li {
    float:left;
    padding-right:30px;
}
.main-menu li.active {
    background-color:blue;
}
.main-menu > li.active .sub-menu {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Obviously it isn't perfect or beautiful, but it should get you on your way.

Comment: Thanks. So you are saying that .active should be added as a jQuery/JavaScript action on click?

Comment: Well, I guess my thought was that the menu would be mostly static, like on the site you referenced, so .active could be added in programmatically when the page loaded. I suppose you could add .active on click. I wrote up a touch of jQuery to help. http://jsfiddle.net/X7T94/1/

Comment: There is only one problem though, which is the main reason I posted this question, that the submenu is not taking different screen widths into account. As you notice, that the main menu is centred in any screen, however the sub menu is always shifted for its location, but not centred, which may not work properly for different widths!

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around it... so you're looking to center the submenu? Just put the `li`s as `display:inline` and the `ul` as `text-align:center`. http://jsfiddle.net/X7T94/2/

Comment: No, center the submenu in relation to the page (i.e, the first submenu item is under the first menu item), however, the submenu background extends all the way to the page edges.

Comment: I updated the description to show you a link to the picture of how I like the page designed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit modified HTML and javascript the following menu works well (tested with IE7-10, Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari):

HTML

```html
<div id="menu-container" class="full-width">
    <div class="full-width-bg"></div>  <!-- this additional div makes red background -->
    <ul class="main-menu normal-width">
        ... etc ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
    border:1px solid green;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    height:3em;
    font-size:21px;
}
.full-width-bg {
    width:100%;
    background: red;
    height:50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:2;
}
.normal-width {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index:3;
    position:relative;
}
.full-width, .full-width-bg {
    min-width: 1024px;
}
ul.main-menu li {
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    position:static;
    text-align:center;
}
ul.main-menu, ul.main-menu ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.main-menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; zoom:1; /* IE7 fix */
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    max-height: 1.5em;
}
ul.main-menu > li {
    background-color:red;
}
ul.main-menu > li > ul > li {
    background-color:orange;
}
ul.main-menu > li > ul > li:hover {
    background-color:yellow;
}
ul.main-menu > li > ul > li:hover > a {
    color:red;
}
ul.main-menu > li > ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
}
.main-menu > li.selected,
ul.main-menu > li:hover > a {
    background-color:#d00;
    color:white;
}
ul.main-menu > li > ul {
    display:none;
    z-index:4;
}
ul.main-menu > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    z-index:5;
}
```

jQuery

```js
$(function () {
    var items = $('.main-menu>li');
    var maxitems = 5; //items.length;
    var current = items[0];
    $('.main-menu li').css('width', (100 / maxitems | 0) + '%');
    items.mouseenter(function(e) {
        $(current).removeClass('selected').children('ul').hide();
        current = this;
        $(current).addClass('selected').children('ul').show();
    });
    items.children('ul').show().end().eq(0).trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7T94/12/show): http://jsfiddle.net/X7T94/12/ - this main menu reserves place for 5 menu links (see javascript)

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to extand the backgrounds of the main menu (the background with color #dfd in your example) and the background color of the submenu (the background with color #ddf in your example) to be the same widh of the page. I am starting to think it is not possible to do that with menu structure.

Comment: Sorry, not quite. I updated the qustion, with a link to the picture, so you can see how I like it done.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `.normal-width` (which defines a width of 1024px) needs to be on your content not on your menu (which you want to be 100% width)

So simply remove it from your menu, and add it to  your content - like so:

```
<div id="menu-container" class="full-width">
   <nav id="nav1">
      ...
   </nav>   
</div>
<div class="content normal-width">Content goes here</div>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/CL5k7/1/)**