# How to adapt bootstrap navbar drop-down to be inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been asked to have inline sub-menu items for a site I'm making using Bootstrap.

The default with Bootstrap for drop-down is a nice 'downdown-toggle' class where items are stacked and only width of items with some padding.

How can I adapt that class for the sub-menu background to be 100% screen width, then sub-menu items in container and items (li's) to be inline not stacked? See mock-up image of what I want to achieve.

Note that unlike the current sub-menu, this would need to push all content below down rather than hover over it.

[image]

**EDIT** after mk14 gave really good code below. This is what I get (see image below). I just need items to be in a container (i've shown in yellow) and to push the content of the page down and back up as menu shows and hides. To reiterate, I want the grey background to be 100% width of screen as I said, but items in the container.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I'm expanding on the first answer based on the comments you made under it and adding more specificity and the media query.

#### http://jsbin.com/rusup/1/edit

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/rusup/1/

---

CSS (add your breakpoint when the larger viewport menu kicks in )

```
@media (min-width:768px) { 
  
  body { padding-top: 60px } /* height of the menu collapsed */

  .nav-bg {
        height: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        background: #e7e7e7;
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .menu-open .nav-bg { height: 50px } /* change to your height of the child menu */
  
    .menu-open #page {
        padding-top:60px;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }

    .navbar-nav.nav > li { position: static }

    .navbar-nav.nav .dropdown-menu {
        left: 0 !important;
        right: 0 !important;
        box-shadow: none;
        border: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1170px;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar-nav.nav .dropdown-menu > li { float: left }

    .navbar-nav.nav .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        width: auto !important;
        background: transparent;
        line-height: 49px;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.navbar').append('<span class="nav-bg"></span>');


$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {

    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {

        $('html').addClass('menu-open');

    } else {

        $('html').removeClass('menu-open');

    }

});


$(document).on('click touchstart', function (a) {
        if ($(a.target).parents().index($('.navbar-nav')) == -1) {
                $('html').removeClass('menu-open');  
        }
});
```

HTML

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2 Child 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2 Child 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2 Child 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2 Child 4</a></li>
          </ul>
         </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
  
<div class="container" id="page">
  Me finks this is a page.
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Nice! Big thank you on this, it's exactly what I needed. The max-width works well in full width mode but I'll need to add rules at the breakpoints like 1199px as it falls out the container again. I removed the ease-in-out transition, nice when it works but jumps about in Chrome and a few others. jQuery append class is a neat solution for move the page content up and down. I've made the navbar sticky when it hits the top of the page ( offset().top and scrollTop ) and used this method to move the page content as it occurs. Thanks again for setting this out :-)

Comment: Nice solution, however one problem is that the second menu closes when you follow a link in it.  What if you want the second menu to be open whilst you are in that section?

Comment: Ask a new question after you make an attempt and work up your code example. I am no longer using Bootstrap or doing much on SO.

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240844/css-full-page-width-horizontal-menu-and-horizontal-submenu)  covers this topic as a general solution.

Here is an adaptation for bootstrap:

```
.nav > li{
position: static !important;
}
.dropdown-menu {
left: 0 !important;
right: 0 !important;
}
.dropdown-menu > li{
float: left !important;
} 
.dropdown-menu > li > a{
width:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: This is really great for the inline items, many thanks mk14. Two key things it needs to do though is: 
1) push the content below down not hover over and most important 
2) items fall in main container not far left of the page
I'll edit my question about with a graphic to illustrate what's happening now I've styled up your code a bit.

Comment: Try adding the same styles to the .dropdown-menu as is on the .container.